# PHP Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit To MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

Couldn't find any good information on how to do this so I thought I'd add it here. How do I grab the selected data from a multiple choice drop down html form using php and submit into a database. I need a seperate row for each choice.

I'd be happy just knowing how to grab the data and put it into an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It gets sent into an array, actually!

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="POST">
<select name="colors[]" multiple="multiple" size="2">
<option>Red</option>
<option>Blue</option>
<option>Green</option>
<option>Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go!"> 
</form>
```

Then in the server side, `$_POST['colors']` will be an array with the selected values.

The key here is to use the bracket notation in the name to let PHP know to expect an array.

For more, [check out the PHP documentation's example](http://www.php.net/variables.external).

Once you have the variables, it is trivial to create new rows.