# PHP Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit To MySQL with OR

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, multi-select

This question is similar to [PHP Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit To MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944158/php-multiple-dropdown-box-form-submit-to-mysql), but with a twist.

Let's assume we have an HTML multi-select, which gets submitted to a PHP backend.

How do you elegantly create a mysql request with an OR condition on the values of a multi-select?

For instance I have a multi-select with a list of sports.
How do do:

```
SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport.name=:sport1 OR sport.name=:sport2 OR sport.name=:sport3...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, just an idea...

```
$_POST['sports'] = array('basketball', 'baseball', 'football', 'soccer');

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport.name IN (%s)", implode( ',', array_fill(1,count($_POST['sports']), '?') ) );
// SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport.name IN (?,?,?,?) 
$st = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// bind all values
foreach( $_POST['sports'] as $i => $sport) {

    $st->bindValue( ++$i, $sport );

}

$st->execute();
```

Comment: Dude, if you typed that without even try it to run it, you are amazing ;-) Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sports.name IN ('football','hockey','soccer','trolling');
```

Comment: This is a good point since I cheched mySQL operators and could not find "IN".
But the question, whether using IN or ORs, is more about the PHP part to generate this from the array my input will produce. And to generate it in a elegant way, because I'm sure I can write an ugly loop with checks on first item, last item and empty array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['sports'] = array('basketball', 'baseball', 'football', 'soccer');

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport.name IN (%s)", implode(',', $_POST['sports']));
```

Should result in

```
SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport.name IN (basketball,baseball,football,soccer)
```