# PHP Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit To MySQL (Part 2)

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is a continuation of the discussion at

[PHP Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit To MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944158/php-multiple-dropdown-box-form-submit-to-mysql)

which ended with the words: "Once you have the variables, it is trivial to create new rows."  No doubt that's generally true, but apparently not for this learner...  :-D

Given the following form:

```
    <form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <select name="colors[]" multiple="yes" size="2">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!"> 
    </form>
```

how do I create new rows?  The following script

```
foreach($_POST['colors[]'] as $color) 
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $color);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO colors SET id = '$id'";
    }
```

raises the error

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form.php on line ...
```

whereas the following

```
    $colors = $_POST['colors[]']; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors); $i++) 
        {
            $color = $colors[$i];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO colors SET id = '$color'";
        }
```

raises no errors but does no row creation.

What triviality am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach($_POST['colors'] as $color)
```

No need to specify `[]` here, php knows that it is an array.

Comment: Yes, however I'm still not getting the database to create rows.  I created a table like so: CREATE TABLE colors (
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
color TEXT
); --- I can't see what the problem is...

Comment: @Peterc: I could not understand your comment completely but why don't you use a sql client software such as sqlyog to create your table?

Comment: @Sarfraz - good suggestion.  I think I found the problem.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What was the problem? It helps for others who encounter the problem to know where you found the problem and an alternative solution for it.

Comment: @Anthony - it was precisely what you said in your answer below - I had left out the mysql_query statement. Doh! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `foreach` loop I did not see that you are executing the query. You need to execute [**`mysql_query`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) with your `INSERT` statement.

```
foreach($_POST['colors'] as $color) {
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $color);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO colors SET id = '$id'";
  if (!mysql_query($sql)) {  // if the query encountered a problem.
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
}
```

Comment: @Anthony - That's correct - as I just discovered (to my chagrin)!  Thanks for the help.